# webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)のところがuse of unresolved identifierと表示される

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searhBar: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var Stop: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var Reload: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var Back: UIBarButtonItem!

    //起動時に開くページ
    let homeUrlString = "https://www.google.co.jp/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ホームページ開く
        open(urlString: homeUrlString)
    }

    //指定したurlをweb viewで開く
    func open(urlString: String){
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url:url!)
        WebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }

    @IBAction func BackButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

    }
    @IBAction func reloadButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

    }

    @IBAction func stopButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

    }
}
```

`WebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)`のところが`use of unresolved identifier`と表示されどこが間違っているのかがわかりません。初心者で参考書どおりにやってたらこうなって...
誰かどこが間違っているか教えてください。
言語はSwiftです

Answer (score 1):

`WebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)` の`WebView`の`W`と`V`が大文字になっています。

プロパティとして定義している`@IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!`では`webview`とすべて小文字なので、同じように書かなければなりません。Swiftでは大文字と小文字は区別されますので、異なると別の変数だと解釈されます。

そのため、定義されてないプロパティを使おうとしたということで`unresolved identifier`というエラーになっています。